# looking for pyMX tutorial

Tags: python

is there any pyMX tutorial ?

> The Python Management Extensions (PyMX) is a Python analog to Java's
>   JMX. PyMX aims to be an API for the management and monitoring of
>   resources such as applications, devices, services, as well as the
>   Python interpreter.